# Проблема с разделением компонента Blazor на представление и логику

Tags: .net, .net-core, blazor

В общем, просто решил поиграться с Blazor.

Прочитал, что для того, что бы разделить компонент на логическую часть и часть представления нужно:

1. Создать класс наследник от `BlazorComponent`, где будет вся логика
2. В представлении вызвать `@inherits` и указать этот класс

Собственно, я так и сделал:

Логика:

```
namespace BlazorTestApp.Pages.Sum
{
    public class SumatorBase : BlazorComponent
    {
        public int CurrentSum { get; set; } = 1;
    }
}
```

Представление:

```
@page "/Sumator"
@using BlazorTestApp.Pages.Sum
@inherits SumatorBase

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Sumator</title>
</head>
<body>213
    <input bind=@CurrentSum />
</body>
</html>
```

Однако, какая-то непонятная ругань:

> Error CS0115  '_Pages_Sum_Sumator.ExecuteAsync()': no suitable method
>   found to override BlazorTestApp
>
> Error CS0115  'Sumator.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder)': no suitable
>   method found to override  BlazorTestApp
>
> Error CS0103  The name 'PageContext' does not exist in the current
>   context   BlazorTestApp

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что информация на которую я наткнулся была устаревшей и теперь нужно наследоваться от `ComponentBase`.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас рекомендуется уже использовать partial class, тогда вы будете избегать кода

```
@inherits SumatorBase
```

Подробнее тут:
https://gunnarpeipman.com/blazor-partial-page-class/